# Twitter Bootstrap Navigation

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, navigation, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm just building a navigation for bootstrap that will get special styles.
The Desktop Clients get a different Style (tabs).

This is the structure I'm using:

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default hidden-lg hidden-md" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                Navigation Title
            </a>
        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navigationcontent">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>
                    <a href="link1">
                        Entry 1
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="link2">
                        Entry 2
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

The Navigation works, but the responsive Design is not working (collapsing to a drop down navigation)

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the id `navigationcontent` to `bs-example-navbar-collapse-1` or vice versa

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
```

You have to make sure that `data-target` should use the valid id or class name of associated `navbar-collapse` div

```
button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
```

[Js Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5TqWB/)

Comment: That fixed it. Also another bug was inside the used php-less library that removed some style definitions so the styles weren't displayed at all. fixed this with another php-less implementation and an update to bootstrap 3.1. THX for the help

Answer (score 0):

You dont have a `navigation menu` that your `drop-down nav` is targeting.
 See  the target here: `data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"`

You need this:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

A reference [here](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar).